# How to verify access token gets from msal() react(Frontend) Azure Active Directory in backend Spring boot from AAD with jwt token(Spring Security)?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, jwt, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I have registered xyz.com domain in Azure Active Directory. Then I registered a React single page app in Azure AD App registrations.
I have successfully authenticated users using MSAL React and obtained access tokens for Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).By msal() react we are getting account details in accounts.

```
accountData {
  "homeAccountId": ".......",
  "environment": "login.windows.net",
  "tenantId": "d..........51",
  "username": "abc@abc.onmicrosoft.com",
  "localAccountId": "9...........09",
  "name": "Abc",
  "idTokenClaims": {
    "aud": "5.......9d",
    "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/d........51/v2.0",
    "iat": 1694666761,
    "nbf": 1694666761,
    "exp": 1694670661,
    "aio": "A........6N",
    "name": "Abc",
    "nonce": "9....sc...",
    "oid": "9........9",
    "preferred_username": "abc@abc.onmicrosoft.com",
    "rh": "0.A......A.",
    "sub": "28.......o",
    "tid": "d.........1",
    "uti": "n......A",
    "ver": "2.0"
  },
  "authorityType": "MSSTS",
  "idToken": "eee...........yyyyy"
}
```

```
//Config.js
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
 
 const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: '5cdsadssand......kjasasda9d',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/d.......asjhdbjhasbdabd...1', 
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000', // Redirect URI after login
    }
  };
  const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  pca.getLogger();
  export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ['user.read'], // Add required scopes
  };
 
  export { msalConfig };
```

```
//Sigin.js
 if (accounts?.length > 0) {
      console.warn("accounts ",instance);
      const accountData = accounts[0];
      dispatch(signupActionMS(accountData));
}
```

As in my app backend(Spring boot) in normal sign(Username and Password) in a jwt token is genrated. And that token is used for futher api calling as Bearer token.

Now, I need to pass these access tokens(Msal React) from frontend (React) to my Spring Boot backend and verify their authorization by Azure active directory.

How can I briefly outline the steps or code snippets to achieve this token verification process in my Spring Boot application? or also how do i handle this access token and Jwt token in Spring boot?

And Also if the msal Access token get expires app also need not handle error and logout the application.